# Can anatomically modern human siblings have three decades of age gap?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction, anthropology

In my story titled La Maison Sapiens, there is a HUGE nuclear family composed of the father, the mother, and their seventeen biological children.

To be exact, the male human being and the female human being, who are the starting members of this nuclear family, were respectively 18 years and 10 months, and 19 years old and 6 months when their first biological child was born. When their second child was born, the father was 22 years and 3 months, and the mother was 22 years old and 11 months. When their third child was born, the father was 26 years old and 5 months, and the mother was 27 years old and 1 month. When their first pair of twins were born, the father was 29 years and 4 months old, and the mother was 30 years and 0 month old. When their second pair of twins were born, the father was 34 years and 1 month old, and the mother was 34 years and 10 months old. When their first set of triplets were born, the father was 39 years and 6 months old, and the mother was 40 years and 2 months old. When their second set of triplets were born, the father was 44 years and 9 months old, and the mother was 45 years and 5 months old. Finally, their last biological children, who are quadruplets, were born when the father was 48 years and 11 months old, and the mother was 49 years and 7 months old.

So, the question is: is it realistic for anatomically modern human siblings to have three decades of age gap?

Note: here is a link about multiple pregnancy : https://www.healthline.com/health/pregnancy/chances-of-having-twins#assisted-reproduction.

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'realistic'. Possible - sure, the constraining factor would be the age of the parents, the Mother in particular. Mother's can have children well into their 70s, so the scenario from this story seems totally plausible. Whether it's common, that's another question...

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234367/can-anatomically-modern-human-siblings-have-three-decades-of-age-gap) from worldbuilding.

Comment: Worth noting, this is a biology site. You should use biological terminology here rather than psychosocial neologisms.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it: 1) lacks evidence of the expected prior research, 2) is unclear (examples: unneeded detail about the exact timing of fictional births, "anatomically modern siblings" doesn't seem to be meaningful), and 3) is crossposted on a more appropriate site. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details of what is expected on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

49 - 19 = 30

So the 1st Child would be 30 when the last children would be born, as long as the parents stay healthy and the mother delivers the child in a natural way (No Surgical Procedure to deliver the child) and the Mother has not had Menopause (Menopause usually happens around 50 Years of age) the sibling age gap would be very possible, but lets take a look at how many children the mother had, if I am correct they had about 16 Children, many people in countries that have a considerably low life expectancy have many children, lets take a look at the world record for most children born from one mother...a person named [Valentina Vassilyev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_the_most_children#:%7E:text=Valentina%20Vassilyev%20and%20her%20husband,a%20total%20of%2027%20births.), gave birth to **69 Children!** Thats a lot of children, so giving birth to 16 children with a 30 age gap should be very possible and realistic as well.

Comment: If you downvote my answer please feel free to say why in the comments. (Somebody Downvoted)

Comment: I'm not the downvote, but you could improve this answer by providing some references to some of the topics (menarche and menopause would be good) and you could also provide data on the oldest natural and potentially the youngest mothers (IIRC, 5 years old, not sure how verifiable this is).